# Wait until require is ready within an angular controller

Tags: angularjs, directive

I need to require a property from a controller from another directive in my main directive, which is easy:

```
return {
...
require['myOtherController'],
link: function(scope,element,attrs,controller){
  scope.propFromOtherCtrl = controller[0].propFromOtherCtrl;
}
```

But: the controller of my directive gets loaded first.
So at first, `propFromOtherCtrl` is undefined in the controller until the link function got executed.

Right now, i am `$scope.$watch`ing the property in my controller until it is defined and then kick off the initialization of my controller manually.

```
//directive controller
$scope.$watch(function(){return $scope.propFromOtherCtrl; },function(n,o){
 if(n !== o){
   // init
 }
});
```

But that seems rather hacky. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?
I can not share the scope between the two directives directly because of the architecture of my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the architecture is the only reason you cannot share the scope between two controllers, you can always use $controller to inherit one controller from the other, then you would have access to its scope regardless of the location in the html dom:

```
$controller('myOtherController', { $scope: $scope });
```

Another alternative is inserting the html part that triggers the directive into an ng-if that doesn't get initialized until the other controller is ready:

```
ng-if="propFromOtherCtrlLoaded"
```

Finally, in case neither of these suit you, using $watch is not that bad, except a small addition, stopping to listen to the changes, would make it more efficient:

```
var unreg = $scope.$watch(function(){return $scope.propFromOtherCtrl; },function(n,o){
 if(n !== o){
   // init
   unreg();
 }
});
```